# Creating a web server for test purposes

Tags: web-development-server

I'm just beginning web
development. I know (to an
extent) the fundamental
languages (Html, CSS &
JavaScript). But I haven't
hosted a webpage before or
rather i haven't managed a
website before and i think for
now, i should be diving into
that (I plan on learning PHP
and a CMS later).

I want to learn the basics of
hosting a website without
actually having a public
website yet. I am actually
thinking if it possible i can
have this private server set up
on my PC which i can use to
host my developed webpages
for the purpose of viewing them
on other devices, just like i'm
hosting a real website but this
time around it is just for
testing purposes.

I haven't registered a domain
name yet. I don't know
if it is possible to have a
virtual domain name too.
I run Ubuntu 14.04 (I just
installed this recently, I am
still learning to use it.) and
windows 8 on my machine.

Comment: Is there some kind of question? ;) However, if you want to set up a local webserver, XAMPP is certainly the easiest way to get one.

Comment: What have you been developing your webpages on so far? If you are using an IDE they are most likely being served up on a server at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

### Local Server

There are several options for local servers. As @lxg pointed out in the comments, [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is probably the easiest way to go. There are others out there as well [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (same idea, but just for Windows, wheras XAMPP is cross-platform).

Another option would be to use a python simple server. [see tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python). This is nice for something super quick & easy.

If you're trying to learn the basics of web hosting, I'd think you'd be better off using XAMPP (or similar). It is easy to set up, but also gives you more power over apache configs and stuff when you get to that point.

---

### Virtual Hosts

As for your question on virtual domains, there are a few ways of doing it. Easiest is to [edit your hosts file](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/). Essentially you'll change `localhost/mysite/index.html` to `mysite.com`. Or you could change it to `google.com` or whatever you wanted. You don't have to have a domain registered for this to work. It's just local. Your computer will check this file before going to querying DNS servers.

As you get more familiar with the local server you use, you can look into [setting up Virtual Hosts](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/)